# Mozilla (Windows 8) Sprite image load issue

Tags: html, css, windows-8, mozilla

I have a very long vertical sprite which i am loading in my web application.
But unfortunately in windows 8 mozilla browser my sprite doesnt load entirely. 
It loads upto a fixed height and ignores the remaining part of the image.

Every time i clear the cache or refresh it load upto that the specific height and ignores the remaining part of the image.

Can anyone give me a reason and the solution to this problem ?

The same sprite image loads absolutely fine in other browsers and also in mozilla (same version) in windows 7. 
I find this issue only in Mozilla for windows 8.

Comment: Note : The length of the image is 14000 pixels in height.

Answer (score 0):

Large images is a known issue for Mozilla: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973667

I don't know if that one qualifies, or the reasoning for having a long one, but I would suggest just going wider, cutting the length down.

Column 1 10px wide 7,000 high, column 2 10x wide, 7,000 high.